Finding additive span of a list, without repeating elements
To demonstrate my problem, say I have a list of $5$ vectors,
list1={1,2,3,4}
list2={5,6,7,8}
list3={9,10,11,12}
list4={13,14,15,16}
list5={17,18,19,20,21}

I want all possible additive combinations (not including adding a list to itself), this is the additive span I suppose. In this example, it would be:
$$(1+2), (1+3), (1+4), (1+5), (2+3), (2+4), (2+5), (3+4), (3+5), (4+5), (1+2+3), (1+2+4), (1+2+5),  (1+3+4), (1+3+5), (1+4+5), (2+3+4), (2+3+5), (2+4+5), (1+2+3+4), (1+2+4+5) (1+3+4+5), (2+3+4+5), (1+2+3+4), (1+2+3+4+5).$$
(Key: $(1+2)$ means list$1$ $+$ list$2$)
If I use the table function, I would get $list1 + list1 + list2$ and $list2 + list1 + list1$ etc. and it would count these twice. I don't want this. I would like a general way of figuring this out, but I can't quite manage it.
I tried creating a list of the lists and multiplying it by binary tuples and deleting the duplicates, but this also deletes important information (e.g if I am working over $Z_{n}$, then I'd be interested if list$i$ $=$ list$j$ + list$k$, but this information doesn't exist if we delete duplicates.)

So e.g. list1+list2 would be {6, 8, 10, 12} ? If so then list5 has five entries. Or do you mean Total all entries?

Subsets[Range[5], {2, 5}]

list5 = {17, 18, 19, 20}; Plus @@@ Subsets[{list1, list2, list3, list4, list5}, {2, 5}]

@user1066, it does indeed! I hadn't thought of the Subset command, but it is very helpful. Thanks all!

Alternative approach using Subsets:
PS: Just saw that this was suggested in comments and acknowledge @azerbajzan and @cvgmt
lists = {
  {1, 2, 3, 4},
  {5, 6, 7, 8},
  {9, 10, 11, 12},
  {13, 14, 15, 16},
  {17, 18, 19, 20, 21}
  }


subsets = Subsets[Range[5]] // Rest


numbers = Extract[lists, List /@ #] & /@ subsets

Total /@ Flatten /@ numbers

(*{10, 26, 42, 58, 95, 36, 52, 68, 105, 68, 84, 121, 100, 137, 153, 78, \
94, 131, 110, 147, 163, 126, 163, 179, 195, 136, 173, 189, 205, 221, \
231}*)


This following can be one way of organizing and visualizing this task. Mainly, I am using indexed lists so that random lists can be generated and accessed. Let me know if you have difficulty tailoring this to your needs.
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[0];
n = 5;

(list[#] = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, RandomInteger[{4, 10}]]) & /@ 
 Range[n]
indices = Subsets[Range[n], {2, Length@Range@n}];
subtotals = 
 indices /. a_Integer :> list[a] // Map[Catenate] // Map[Total]

labels = TextString[#, ListFormat -> {"(", "+", ")"}] & /@ indices;

result = Thread[labels -> subtotals] // TableForm 

p1 = NumberLinePlot[{
    Tooltip[#1, #2] & @@@ Transpose@{subtotals, labels}
    , Interval@MinMax@subtotals
    }
   , ImageSize -> 600
   ];

p2 = ListLinePlot[
   Tooltip[subtotals -> labels]
   , ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
   , Mesh -> All
   , ImageSize -> 600
   , PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.15]
   , GridLines -> {None, MinMax@subtotals}
   , Ticks -> {Automatic, MinMax@subtotals}
   , AxesOrigin -> {-5, 0}
   , AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio
   , PlotLegends -> BarLegend[
     {"Rainbow", MinMax[subtotals]}
     , LegendMarkerSize -> 180
     , Ticks -> MinMax@subtotals
     ]
   ];


Grid[List /@ {p2, p1}]


